# What's the use of output gate of LSTM?

Tags: lstm

According to the LSTM structure, the memory cell is outputed to the next layer or the hidden layer of the next time step, through an output gate. However, it is exposed directly to the input,forget and output gate of the next time step. What's the benefit of this selective degree of exposure?

Answer (score 0):

**Forget Gate**: This is a matrix of 0's and 1's which filter out the 
outputs,you don't need or aren't necessary to carry further.

**Update Gate**: This is also a matrix of 0's and 1's which tells which outputs are to be updated after forgetting them, because you can't remember and forget a thing simultaneously, so we are replacing the outputs with newer outputs.

**example**: My cat is very beautiful. She eats only fish. Other cats are very rude to her.

here, at first we were talking about only one cat, but we want our model such that when it encounters the word "cats", the model should forget about previous singular "cat", get an update and output "are" instead of "is". But in order to predict "are" we need another filter which helps us in figuring out the possible candidates for the prediction, and here enters the output gate.

**Output Gate**: It is also a matrix of 0's and 1's and it helps in deciding which outputs we will use, and after applying this, we provide the resultant matrix to softmax to calculate the probabilities, deciding who is the winner candidate for the prediction.

Comment: you can read this for more info: https://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/